# retrieve email id from "to" field using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, email

I have made application that send a mail in group of 1000 people.
In the mail i have put one link to "like" my product.

whenever user click on that link, my mail should return his/her email id in back and redirect to success page.

now my question is 
How to retrieve email address of that user out of 1000 email.

-thanks

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question - it currently makes no sense.

Comment: is there anything you have tried out? and the question is very unclear

Comment: I have send email to multiple user.
in that email content it contain "send data" link. whenever user click on it, the mail should return user's address.

-thanks for quick reply.

Comment: if you have sent the email already that means you know there email address, so y retrieve it back again

Comment: may be you want to see whether they actually clicked your link for actual email validity, is that what u want?

Comment: Why not to add "TO" address into the link "send data" while sending email?

Comment: @Vims : so u have your own prog using some mail api ???

Comment: @Swarnajith - actually i have sent it in group mail, so i am not able to get it individually.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid -- yes sir.

Comment: you should add more details with what you have tried, otherwise its difficult to answer

Comment: hey dont call me sir , btw just when you click send button call a JQuery function $('#IDofTOtextfield').val() , is this something helpful , fits in your scenario ????

Comment: @Swarnajith,Rory McCrossan - is my question clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

No email client will run JavaScript embedded in an email. For that matter, there are quite a lot that don't even support forms.

If you want to collect data from people you send emails to, and you want to know which user it is, then include a link in the email to a form on your webserver. You can pass the email address (or some other identifier) in the query string and use that to pre-populate the form.

Beware the possibility of recipients forwarding the email to other people. They'll forward the link their their identifying token.